# Displaying div if radio button is checked

Tags: html, css

I have a radio button which id is `someID-1` and a div which id is `navi1`.

```
<input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-1" />

<div>&nbsp;
  <div id="navi1">
    <div style="z-index:100;position:fixed;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;">
      <label for="someID-2">2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This CSS code works just fine:

```
div[id^="navi"] {
  display: none;
}
```

But this does not work OK:

```
input#someID-1:checked #navi1 {
  display: block;
}
```

How should I modify the code?

I have tens of radio buttons (id names between `someID-1` and `someID-99`). I would like to have dynamic code.

I do not want to use JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have some restriction on using JavaScript?

Comment: I just prefer using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make like this. you can read the details of the selector that i used [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
#navi1{
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]#someID-1:checked + div #navi1{
 display: block;
}
.box{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-1" />

<div class="box">&nbsp;
  <div id="navi1">
    <div>
      <label for="someID-2">2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate the document hierarchy correctly in your CSS.  So this works:

```
div[id^="navi"]
{
    display: none;
}

#someID-1:checked + div div {
    display:block;
}
```